# What does the second word after FROM mean in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

A legacy application I'm working on has a SQL query that selects several attributes from a table. In this `restaurant_chef_hats` table, I can run a query like the one below:

`SELECT FirstName FROM restaurant_chef_hats;`

A few queries have a second parameter after `FROM`, but before several `LEFT JOIN` operations take place.

Given a query like...

`SELECT FirstName FROM restaurant_chef_hats employees LEFT JOIN ON (~~ some criteria ~~ )`

...what is the significance of the `employees` parameter?

**EDIT**

Further context: This is within the context of a command that creates a new MySQL database based off of existing tables. Here is the full query, with table/column names changed. My question, in this example, pertains to the purpose of the word `hatser` within `FROM loccodeofchats hatser`.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `restaurant_chef_hats`;
CREATE TABLE restaurant_chef_hats AS
    SELECT
        hatser.TakeoutID,
        hats_dish.TakeoutID as cooked_dish_id,
        member.RestabName As chef_title,
        prefix.PrefixCode as Prefix,
        suffix.SuffixCode as Suffix,
        hatser.Title,
        roles.LUTOrder AS Rank,
        address.TypeID,
        hatser.AppetizerID as SouschefID,
        hatser.AppetizerID_2 as SouschefID_2,
        hatser.AppetizerID_3 as SouschefID_3,
        roles.RoleDescShort as RoleDesc,
        roles2.RoleDescShort as RoleDesc_2,
        roles3.RoleDescShort as RoleDesc_3,
        dish.FirstName,
        dish.LastName,
        dish.MiddleName,
        dish.NickName,
        fork.ForkDesc,
        sweet.SweetDesc,
        register.RegisterDesc,
        address.P_Room,
        address.P_Building,
        address.P_Street,
        address.P_Street2,
        state.StateAbbr,
        address.P_City,
        address.P_ZipCode,
        dish.LastUpdated,
        hats_dish.BirthdayPartyID,
        party.PartyCode,
        party.PartyDesc,
        address_type.AddressTypeDesc,
        CONCAT('(', phone.AreaCode,') ', phone.Phone) as Telephone,
        CONCAT('(', fax.AreaCode,') ', fax.Phone) as Fax,
        stats.MaritalStatusDesc,
        dish.CreationPlace,
        dish.CreationYear,
        dish.CreationMonth,
        dish.CreationDate,
        dish.WineCouplingName,
        dish.Origin,
        dish.Family,
        CONCAT_WS(' ',hats_dish.FirstName,hats_dish.LastName) as officeOf
    FROM loccodeofchats hatser
        LEFT JOIN loccodeofc member ON (hatser.FoodRestabID=member.FoodCounterID AND member.SouschefID=47 AND member.StateID = 0)
        LEFT JOIN soups dish ON (hatser.TakeoutID=dish.TakeoutID)
        LEFT JOIN soups hats_dish ON (member.TakeoutID=hats_dish.TakeoutID)
        LEFT JOIN soupsaddresses address ON (hatser.TakeoutID=address.TakeoutID AND address.DisplayOrder=1)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantgeneralstates state ON (state.StateID=address.P_StateID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantlegbirthdayparties party ON (hats_dish.BirthdayPartyID=party.FoodBirthdayPartyID)
        LEFT JOIN soupsphones phone ON (phone.TakeoutID=hatser.TakeoutID AND phone.TypeID=1)
        LEFT JOIN soupsphones fax ON (fax.TakeoutID=hatser.TakeoutID AND fax.TypeID=2)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantdesserts roles ON (hatser.AppetizerID=roles.AppetizerID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantdesserts roles2 ON (hatser.AppetizerID_2=roles2.AppetizerID AND hatser.AppetizerID_2 IS NOT NULL)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantdesserts roles3 ON (hatser.AppetizerID_3=roles3.AppetizerID AND hatser.AppetizerID_3 IS NOT NULL)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonsprefix prefix ON prefix.PrefixID=dish.PrefixID
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonssuffix suffix ON suffix.SuffixID=dish.SuffixID
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonsfork fork ON (fork.ForkID=dish.ForkID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonssweet sweet ON (sweet.SweetID=dish.SweetID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonsregister register ON (register.RegisterID=dish.RegisterID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantspoonsmaritalstatus stats ON (stats.MaritalStatusID=dish.MaritalStatusID)
        LEFT JOIN restaurantroleaddresstypes address_type ON (address.TypeID = address_type.AddressTypeID)
    WHERE hats_dish.TakeoutID != 165208
    GROUP BY hatser.TakeoutID, hatser.FoodRestabID;

ALTER TABLE restaurant_chef_hats ADD pk_column INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE restaurant_chef_hats ADD INDEX Updated_Index (LastUpdated);
ALTER TABLE restaurant_chef_hats ADD INDEX TakeoutID_Index (TakeoutID);
ALTER TABLE restaurant_chef_hats ADD INDEX Ordered_TakeoutID_Index (cooked_dish_id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a table name alias ..

```
 FROM loccodeofchats hatser
```

once you have used  this you can refer to the column name of the table  `loccodeofchats`  an `hatser`

so the column  `loccodeofchats .AppetizerID`   became `hatser.AppetizerID`

and  in your query this column is redefined with th alias `SouschefID`
the alis are often used  for better readblity  or for a more simple code aspect.. ...

> The use of table aliases is to rename a table in a specific SQL
>   statement. The renaming is a temporary change and the actual table
>   name does not change in the database. The column aliases are used to
>   rename a table's columns for the purpose of a particular SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for this, that was very helpful! Without knowing to look for alias, I was having a hard time finding examples of the FROM {{ tablename }} having an alias. I think I'm much closer now to understanding what this thing is doing!

Answer (score 3):

That is called an Alias and as you said it is kind of nickname. You can declare them with as `AS` operator also. You can get more info from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . `as` is supported, I believe, in every database other than Oracle.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I stand corrected. MySQL supports it as well as PostgreSQL. Oracle does not. I'll upvote.

Comment: You can alias (as) for a table or a column. @TheImpaler Follow the link below for some examples.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 2):

This is called a *table alias*.  It is a way of naming the reference to the table.  As a best practice, define the table alias as a reasonable abbreviation of the table name.  So:

```
FROM restaurant_chef_hats rch
```

Rather than:

```
FROM restaurant_chef_hats a
```

Explicit table aliases are required in two cases:

1. When the same table is referred to more than one one time in the `FROM` clause.
2. For derived tables (aka subqueries) in the `FROM` clause.

In fact, you can think of all tables as having aliases, with the default alias being the full table name.  It is usually easier to read and write queries using aliases than with the longer table names.

Answer (score 2):

Like most have replied here, it's called an alias, personally I use it to shorten my query especially in cases where you have JOINS, you just give your tables a short alias/label that'll make your SELECT shorter and also would help if table names in a query are too similar